# launch command line from java without knowing OS

Tags: java

Is there a way to launch the command line from java without knowing OS? For example, the method would open up the terminal shell for a Linux OS and open the command line for Windows.

I do know (from looking at previous questions) that i can just check the OS and then open the proper command line, but is there a way to open the command line from a java method that is OS agnostic?

Comment: You could have an environment variable set on the system and then use that to open the commandLine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct or uniform way of doing that across the platforms. One way you can accomplish is

1. Determine the OS (using `System.getProperty("os.name")`).
2. Then depending on the OS, execute OS specific command.

for example: (snippet taken from [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-detect-os-in-java-systemgetpropertyosname/) )

```
           String OS = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();

        if (isWindows(OS)) {
            String path = "c:\\";
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "cmd.exe", "/C", "\"start; cd "+path+"\"" });;
        } else if (isMac(OS)) {
            //Open Mac Prompt
        } else if (isUnix(OS)) {
            //Open UnixPrompt
        } else if (isSolaris(OS)) {
            //Open Solaris Prompt
        } else {
            System.out.println("Your OS is not support!!");
        }

public static boolean isWindows(String OS) {

        return (OS.indexOf("win") >= 0);

    }

    public static boolean isMac(String OS) {

        return (OS.indexOf("mac") >= 0);

    }

    public static boolean isUnix(String OS) {

        return (OS.indexOf("nix") >= 0 || OS.indexOf("nux") >= 0 || OS.indexOf("aix") > 0 );

    }

    public static boolean isSolaris(String OS) {

        return (OS.indexOf("sunos") >= 0);

    }
```

Please look for the relevant code for different OS

Note: its just a code snippet. It won't compile as is.

Answer (score 0):

The command:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("command")
```

will work on all desktop/laptop OS platforms.

Comment: What do you mean by "command"? Is it a placeholder or "command" is actually a command?

Answer (score 0):

Once Java is installed on any OS, all you do is use it to create your own programs. The command line in Windows or Terminal in Linux are property of the OS.

So, even if there was an API in Java to open a terminal directly, that method would internally check for the Operating System as well.